# How to secure folder on server without php scripts

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, security, http, authentication

I have a number of .html files on my web-server which I store in a specific folder. I have to protect them from unwanted users and let only a few people to be able to access this folder.

I would like to protect this specific folder, so users have to log in, but I don't want to use any PHP framework etc. It's only a simple HTML website created without PHP.

I have my own dedicated server, so there are some options to do it. For now I did basic HTTP Auth based on .htaccess and .htpasswd files, but I've just read it's no really secure because password is sent as plain text. I've found a similar option called .htdigest, but maybe there are more secure and also easy to set up ways to secure folder? Hope someone can recommend me a method to make it secure? Here is what I have on my server:

- using CloudFlare Service (paid plan) which allows me to use SSL,
- can install additional modules if needed.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use allow/deny directive

Order allow,deny
  Deny from all

it will give user response code 403 forbidden page but if you want to return 404 response code then you can use below

RedirectMatch 404

references : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html

Comment: I understand, but this is not what I'm asking for. I would like to display login form for users and make it secure. As I said I've read that HTTP Auth is not secure, so I'm looking for a similar login method which is more secure.